# How to change X and Y axis numbers' colour in GraphView for Android?

Tags: android-graphview

I'm using GraphView in my app to display a realtime graph from the magnetic field sensor values.

Initialized the GraphView object as follows:

```
GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
...
```

and set data series and grid colour using the following:

```
...
graph.addSeries(series);
...
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(Color.RED);
```

And I get this as a result.

[Graph with numbers I want to change highlited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99CBY.png)

Now I want to remove the X and Y axis value numbers indicated in the above picture by green arrows, how can I do that? If they can't be removed, how can I change their font colour? I'll make it match the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found what I was looking for, to disable the X and Y numbers along the axes, use:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsVisible(false);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsVisible(false);
```